# TypeScript Recursively References with MobX Stores

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, mobx

I have a TypeScript Recursively References issue. I spend two days trying to figure this out and really need some help.

I using MobX and I have one parent store and two child stores. Below is an overview of my setup. Take note on how I pass the parent store to the child stores. ([Example App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-discussions-2536-v4?file=src%2FDashboardPage.store.ts))

```js
// ChartWidget.store.ts
const ChartWidgetStore = (dashboardPageStore: IDashboardPageStore) => observable({ /*...*/ });

// TableWidget.store.ts
const TableWidgetStore = (dashboardPageStore: IDashboardPageStore) => observable({ /*...*/ });

// DashboardPageStore.store.ts
export const DashboardPageStore = () => {
  const store = observable({
    chartWidgetStore = null,
    tableWidgetStore = null,
  });

  store.chartWidgetStore = ChartWidgetStore(store);
  store.tableWidgetStore = TableWidgetStore(store);

  return store;
};

export interface IDashboardPageStore extends ReturnType<typeof DashboardPageStore> {}
```

If I give the child/widget stores a type:

```js
chartWidgetStore: null as IChartWidgetStore,
tableWidgetStore: null as ITableWidgetStore,
```

I get the error: `Type 'IDashboardPageStore' recursively references itself as a base type.(2310)` and all my types become `any`. I Think they become `any` because of the `ReturnType` type getting confused with the recursively references.

[image]

Here is a [Example App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-discussions-2536-v4?file=src%2FDashboardPage.store.ts)

Answer (score 0):

- `IChartWidgetStore` is used for a property of `DashboardPageStore`
- `DashboardPageStore` is used to derive the type for `IDashboardPageStore`
- `IDashboardPageStore` is used to type the argument of `ChartWidgetStore`
- `ChartWidgetStore` is used to derive the type `IChartWidgetStore` ...and now we've come full circle.

If the children depend on the parents, then the parents cannot depend on the children, and vice-versa.

Comment: Ya I hear ya but if the app is working and not having issues because of the full circle references then why can't the types work? If I write this with classes and they had the same references it would work.

Comment: You can always just `//@ts-ignore` if you don't want to restructure anything.